# How to use rows of different cardinality with union

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

How can I write the following SQL query in jOOQ?

```
select row (user1."surname", user1."id") from "user" as user1
union all
select row (user2."id") from "user" as user2
```

Doing it like this does not compile, because the two rows are `Row2` and `Row1`, which are not the same type, obviously.

```
db.select(row(user1.SURNAME, user1.ID)).from(user1)
.unionAll(select(row(user2.ID)).from(user2))
.fetch()
```

The only workaround solution I found is using `row(Collection<?> values)`, however it seems like there must be a better way of doing it.

```
db.select(row(listOf(user1.SURNAME, user1.ID))).from(user1)
.unionAll(select(row(listOf(user2.ID))).from(user2))
.fetch()
```

Comment: This is probably quite vendor specific, so what RDBMS are you using? Also, why do you think that "workaround" isn't good enough?

Comment: I use Postgres. A perfect solution from my point of view would be to use `row(SelectField<?>... values)`. This would then have a similar syntax to raw SQL, and thus be more intuitive to recognize. However, I could not find a way to just import `row(SelectField<?>... values)` without importing the type safe row builders.

Comment: Well, you could always add ~22 dummy parameters to get rid of type safety ;-)

Comment: I can also just build JSON instead of using row. JSON actually works like a charm for my use case. I was just curious whether I misunderstood the row constructor or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be "how can I tell the compiler to prefer the varargs overload `row(SelectField...)` over the typed overloads such as `row(SelectField, SelectField)` in order to get rid of type safety.

There isn't really any better way than using `listOf()` or `*arrayOf()` (with the spread operator) in Kotlin, just like in Java you'd have to use `List.of()` or `new SelectField[] { ... }` to tell the compiler to use the collection overloads, because varargs overloads are always deprioritised by the compilers if there's a more specific, applicable overload. Usually, this is the desired behaviour because usually, you *want* type safety.